# Needing guidance with introductory level set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm struggling quite a bit with set theory in one of my computer science classes.  I'm not looking for an answer directly, but maybe help in the form of pointing out if I'm anywhere near on the correct path or if I'm totally approaching the solutions wrong.

I'm being asked to turn each statement into a well-formed formula that doesn't contain the power set symbol (P).  I'm entirely confused if I'm using the correct notation.

In 1, I'm not sure if I should be using `(X ⊆ A)` or `(X ∈ A)` in the final answer.  My mind is telling me that x must be a set, since it belongs to the power set, so I should be using `⊆` to denote its a set and not `∈`.

```
1) X ∈ P(A ∪ B) ⇔ (X ⊆ A) ∨ (X ⊆ B) (By definition of power set)
```

I'm entirely confused with problem 2 and am not sure how to approach it, as the statement seems to be about x and just kind of randomly throws in P(B)

```
2) X ∈ P(A) ∪ P(B) ⇔ (X ⊆ A) ∨ B
```

Comment: As it is, the expression $\;(X\subset A)\vee B\;$ doesn't make much sense, *even* if you actually meant $\;(X\subset A)\cup B\;$ Perhaps you meant $\;(X\subset A)\;\vee\,(X\subset B)\;$ ...?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what I need.  The left side of the problem was provided, so this: **X ∈ P(A) ∪ P(B)**, is exactly what were supposed to rewrite without (P).  I can read that X is a subset of A, but I don't know if I can assume the same for x in relation to P(B), since there isn't another statement about **X ∈ P(B).**

Comment: Definition : $X \in P(A)$ **iff** $X \subseteq A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with words: $\;X\in P(A)\cup P(A)\;$ means "$X$ is *an element* of $\;P(A)\;$ or of $\;P(B)\;$ , and this means $\;X\;$ is a subset of $\;A\;$ or a subset of $\;B\;$ , so wer could write

$$X\in P(A)\cup P(B)\iff X\subset A\;\;\text{or}\;\;X\subset B$$

Observe that in (higher) mathematics it is usually agreed that $\;\subset\;$ means *weak* inclusion: it is either a subset **or ** the whole subset.

For the other one ((1)), we have

$$X\in P(A\cup B)\iff X\subset A\cup B\ldots\;\text{and that's all}$$

We cannot deduce $\;X\subset A\;$ *or* $\;X\subset B\;$ as both can be false, for example:

$$\begin{cases}A=\{1,2\}\\B=\{3\}\end{cases}\;\;\implies\;\;X=\{1,3\}\in P(A\cup B)=P(\{1,2,3\})$$

Comment: I think that your assertion about the meaning of $\subset$ is much too strong: in my experience it very often means strict inclusion. Frankly, it’s best avoided altogether in anything intended for eyes other than one’s own. E.g., while I use $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ when writing only for myself, I routinely use $\subsetneqq$ and $\subseteq$ here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott My assertions was that **usually** . If you want, change that to sometimes or whatever. All the time while in university I took that as weak inclusion. You can read about this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset , or here: http://www.abstractmath.org/MM/MMOtherSymbols.htm#inclusion . I think that whoever wants to make things strictly clear, use $\;\subsetneq\;$